# Javascript carousel making me click twice sometimes

Tags: javascript

just learning Javascript here. I made a little image carousel with a previous button. It mostly works, but sometimes I have to click it twice for it to actually change. Any insight on why it's doing that and how I can fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/2t79qw4r/6/

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = ["_images/overlook.jpg", "_images/winery_sign.jpg", "_images/lunch.jpg", "_images/bigSur.jpg", "_images/flag_photo.jpg", "_images/mission_look.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
var prevImage = document.getElementById("prev");

function changeImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

prevImage.onclick = function() {
  if (imageIndex === 0) {
    imageIndex = imageArray.length -1;
  } else {
    imageIndex = imageIndex - 1;
  }
  myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);

};

setInterval(changeImage,3000);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your `changeImage` function is reversed; update the value before setting it:

```
function changeImage() {
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afptfbs8/